# How do you add a checkbox to the start of a list item in HTML without altering the size of the list item

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I am using jQuery's ajax library to build a list to display.

The list looks like this:

```
<ul id="results">
<li onclick="convener_selected('1')">mister 1</li>
<li onclick="convener_selected('2')">mister 2</li>
<li onclick="convener_selected('2')">mister 3</li>
</ul>
```

Now, when I click on each item of the list, even on the blank part, the on click event fires normally.

However, I added a checkbox at the start of the list with these methods:

a)

```
 <li><input type="checkbox" value="1"> <span  onclick="convener_selected('1')">mister 1</span> </li>
```

b)

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
<li onclick="convener_selected('1')">mister 1</li>
```

c)

```
<li><input type="checkbox" value="1"> <div  onclick="convener_selected('1')">mister 1</div></li>
```

The problem with a) is that now I have to click on the letters of mister 1 in order for the on click event to fire.
The problem with b) and c) is that they appear in different lines, if I add:

```
style="display:in-line;"
```

then in c) it behaves like the span (i.e. it only works if I click on the letters) and in b) it looks awful.

Is there something that I can do to keep the old functionality, while adding a checkbox at the start?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: make a fiddle please.

Comment: here is what I have now : https://jsfiddle.net/L9o8z8e9/3/ and here is what I want to do https://jsfiddle.net/L9o8z8e9/4/ only in the second case I wish for the whole grey part to be clickable and show the alert, not just the letters

Comment: see the answer and please remove the `list-style` from `li`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your HTML only:

**Updated HTML:**

```
<ul id="results">
  <li><input type="checkbox"><span onClick="alert('1')">mister 1</span></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox"><span onClick="alert('2')">mister 2</span></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox"><span onClick="alert('3')">mister 3</span></li>
</ul>
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/L9o8z8e9/8/)

Comment: Unfortunatelly this doesn't work for me cause onclick fires when you also click the checkbox, I only wish for it to fire when clicking anything but the checkbox

Comment: @Cruces, you said: `only in the second case I wish for the whole grey part to be clickable and show the alert, not just the letters`.

Now what you want?